# Retrofit 2.0 beta 1 with whole URL

Tags: android, retrofit

In retrofit 2.0 i want to use only one url .The url is same as base url as that of @GET in interface.I am facing the problem for getting the response.If Any one have better solution for using the whole url in @GET then please suggest the solution.
here is the code

```
    public class RestClient {

        private static ApiInterface apiInterface ;

        private static String baseUrl = "here is my  whole base url";



        public static ApiInterface getClient() {
            if (apiInterface == null) {

                OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient();
                okClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

                        return response;
                    }
                });

                Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                        .addConverter(String.class, new ToStringConverter())
                        .client(okClient)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
                apiInterface = client.create(ApiInterface.class);
                Log.e("RETROFIT RESPONCE IS...", client.toString());

            }
            return ApiInterface ;
        }

    public interface ApiInterface {

            @Headers("User-Agent: Retrofit2.0Tutorial-App")
            @GET("here is my  whole base url”)
            Call<EventResult> getEvent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide your code and point where is problem.

Answer (score 3):

With retrofit 2 is possible to use the `@Url` annotation. Let's assume your Retrofit configuration is

```
Retrofit builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://wwww.example.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
Test r = builder.create(Test.class);
```

you declare your interface:

```
public interface Test {
      @GET
      Call<Example> getTest(@Url String url);
 }
```

and for `getTest` you don't want to use the baseUrl you declared in the configuration. The `@Url` will ignore the  baseUrl you declared and will use the one you provide as argument

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible since BaseURL is mandatory in Retrofit Builder and even you supply the builder with the full URL the builder will parse it and save only the BaseURL. I guess the reason why they do this is to keep it simple and consistent.

for reference you can see the source code [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/Retrofit.java#L302)